# Redmine install on Apache2/Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ruby, amazon-ec2, redmine

Can someone point me to a guide or guides that explain how to get Redmine running on Ubuntu 12.04?  From installing Ruby to setting up Passenger?  I've tried a handful of times and have never been successful, I'm more of a C/PHP developer, never really had the cause to use Ruby until now.  Thanks.

Comment: Lazy way is to use the cloud images from Bitnami - http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine

Comment: [Super Easy video on How to Install BitNami Redmine AND PLUGINS](http://redminecrm.com/boards/4/topics/1153)

Comment: a)[How to install Redmine using Bitnami Redmine Stack](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/How_to_install_Redmine_in_Linux_Windows_and_OS_X_using_BitNami_Redmine_Stack),    b)[Installing BitNami Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTos#Bitnami)

Comment: a)[BitNami Redmine Wiki](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Redmine),  b)(Setting up email for Redmine on Amazon Cloud](http://bitnami.com/forums/forums/redmine/topics/setting-up-email-for-redmine-on-amazon)

Answer (score 0):

I've ordered this list from the viewpoint of being a complete ALM (or SDE) solution but if you would inspect it from the viewpoint of documentation and support, Clinker should go to the bottom of it. Clinker is a complete tool like Microsoft's TFS-VS-MTM package but you will have too much administration, customization, maintenance headache. Bitnami is the most widely known stack if you just want Redmine. You can even later integrate it with other Bitnami stacks like Alfresco, Jenkins or other software related solutions like Sonarqube either in an isolated fashion (separate stacks on separate VMs or servers) or all together on the same stack. Turnkeylinux is just another stack that I just observed from a distance. Looks like an Ok stack but I don't know the details of it.

http://clinkerhq.com/products#va
http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine